# Как записать в структуру содержимое другой структуры?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct word{
    char* syms;
};

struct sentense{
    struct word** words;
};

struct text{
    struct sentense*** sentenses;
};

int main() {
    struct word word;
    struct sentense sentense;
    struct text text;


    word.syms = (char *) malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    sentense.words = (struct word **) malloc(100 * sizeof(struct word *));
    text.sentenses = (struct sentense***) malloc(100 * sizeof(struct sentense**));

    word.syms[0] = '1';
    word.syms[1] = '2';
    sentense.words[0] = (struct word *) malloc(sizeof(word));
    word.syms[2] = 0;

    sentense.words[0]->syms = strdup(word.syms);

    word.syms[0] = '4';
    word.syms[1] = '5';
    sentense.words[1] = (struct word *) malloc(sizeof(word));
    sentense.words[1]->syms = strdup(word.syms);

    text.sentenses[0] = (struct sentense **) malloc(sizeof(sentense));
    text.sentenses[0]->words  = strdup(sentense.words);

    printf("%s", sentense.words[0]->syms);
    printf("%s", sentense.words[1]->syms);
    printf("%s", text.sentenses[0]->words);

    return 0;
}
```

Я создаю два слова, затем слова записываю в предложение. Затем хочу предложение записать в текст, но не получается. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Структура `text` неправильна. В ней должно быть список предложений, а не граф.

```
struct text{
  struct sentense * sentenses;
};
```

В предложении тоже самое нужен список слов.

```
struct sentense{
  struct word* words;
};
```

В для предложения выделяете указатель на 100 слов. Но слова при этом не инициилизированы ничем. Для этих слов нужно им выделять память индивидуально.

```
struct text text;
text.sentenses = (struct sentense*) malloc(100 * sizeof(struct sentense));
// место для ста предложений выделили
for (int i=0;i<100;++i){
  // этим каждым предложениям нужно выделить память для слов
  text.sentenses[i].words = (struct word *) malloc(100 * sizeof(struct word));
  for (int j=0;j<100;++j)
    // и для каждого для слова у каждого предложения выделяем память для букв
    text.sentenses[i].words[j].syms = (char *) malloc(100 * sizeof(char));}
```

---

Вот пример получше, в структуре будут поля размеров веделенной памяти и уже использованный с данными. А также функции для копии этих структур. Функцию для печати вы можете дописать сами.

```
// gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c11 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L text.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct word{
  int size  ;
  int maxsize ;
    char* syms;
};

struct word worddup(struct word w ) {
  struct word r ;
  r.size = w.size;
  r.maxsize = w.maxsize;
  r.syms = strdup (w.syms);
  return r;
}

struct sentense{
  int size  ;
  int maxsize ;
  struct word* words;
};

struct sentense sentensedup(struct sentense  s ) {
  struct sentense r ;
  r.size = s.size;
  r.maxsize = s.maxsize;
  r.words = malloc(sizeof(struct word) * r.maxsize);
  for(int i = 0; i < r.size ; ++i)
    r.words[i] = worddup ( s.words[i] ) ;
  return r;
}

struct text{
  int size  ;
  int maxsize ;
  struct sentense * sentenses;
};

struct text textdup(struct text  t ) {
  struct text r ;
  r.size = t.size;
  r.maxsize = t.maxsize;
  r.sentenses = malloc(sizeof(struct sentense) * r.maxsize);
  for(int i = 0; i < r.size ; ++i)
    r.sentenses[i] = sentensedup ( t.sentenses[i] ) ;
  return r;
}

int main(){
struct text text;
text . size = 60 ;
text . maxsize = 100 ;
text.sentenses = (struct sentense*) malloc(
  text . maxsize * sizeof(struct sentense));
// место для ста предложений выделили
for (int i=0;i<text . size;++i){
  text.sentenses[i].size = 60 ;
  text.sentenses[i].maxsize = 100 ;
  // этим каждым предложениям нужно выделить память для слов
  text.sentenses[i].words = (struct word *) malloc(
    text.sentenses[i].maxsize * sizeof(struct word));
  for (int j=0;j<text.sentenses[i].size;++j){
    text.sentenses[i].words[j].size = 0 ;
    text.sentenses[i].words[j].maxsize = 100 ;
    // и для каждого для слова у каждого предложения выделяем память для букв
    text.sentenses[i].words[j].syms = (char *) malloc(
      text.sentenses[i].words[j].maxsize * sizeof(char));}}
}
```

Comment: Учел ваши замечания, но все равно не понимаю почему 
```
text.sentences[0].words = strdup(sentence.words);
    printf("%s",text.sentences[0].words);
``` 
не выводит предложения

Comment: `words` - указывает на структуру, а не на строку. скорее всего вы хотели скопировать слово, тогда так  : `text.sentences[0].words[0].syms = strdup(sentence.words[0].syms);` А если копировать предложение, тогда циклом указатели копируйте.

Comment: дописал функцию копии строк. А печатать допишете сами.